# Getting an error while importing tensorflow and keras libraries

Tags: tensorflow, keras, import

import tensorflow as tf
import keras both are showing the same error

```
"name": "ImportError",
    "message": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py\", line 58, in <module>\n    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *\n  File \"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py\", line 28, in <module>\n    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()\n  File \"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py\", line 24, in swig_import_helper\n    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)\n  File \"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/imp.py\", line 243, in load_module\n    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)\n  File \"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/imp.py\", line 343, in load_dynamic\n    return _load(spec)\nImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so, 0x0006): tried: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so' (no such file), '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64'))\n\n\nFailed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.\n\nSee https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors\n\nfor some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace\nabove this error message when asking for help.",
    "stack": "\u001b[0;31m---------------------------------------------------------------------------\u001b[0m\n\u001b[0;31mImportError\u001b[0m                               Traceback (most recent call last)\nFile \u001b[0;32m/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py:58\u001b[0m\n\u001b[1;32m     56\u001b[0m   sys\u001b[39m.\u001b[39msetdlopenflags(_default_dlopen_flags \u001b[39m|\u001b[39m ctypes\u001b[39m.\u001b[39mRTLD_LOCAL)\n\u001b[0;32m---> 58\u001b[0m \u001b[39mfrom\u001b[39;00m \u001b[39mtensorflow\u001b[39;00m\u001b[39m.\u001b[39;00m\u001b[39mpython\u001b[39;00m\u001b[39m.\u001b[39;00m\u001b[39mpywrap_tensorflow_internal\u001b[39;00m \u001b[39mimport\u001b[39;00m \u001b[39m*\u001b[39m\n\u001b[1;32m     59\u001b[0m \u001b[39mfrom\u001b[39;00m \u001b[39mtensorflow\u001b[39;00m\u001b[39m.\u001b[39;00m\u001b[39mpython\u001b[39;00m\u001b[39m.\u001b[39;00m\u001b[39mpywrap_tensorflow_internal\u001b[39;00m \u001b[39mimport\u001b[39;00m __version__\n\nFile \u001b[0;32m/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py:28\u001b[0m\n\u001b[1;32m     27\u001b[0m         \u001b[39mreturn\u001b[39;00m _mod\n\u001b[0;32m---> 28\u001b[0m _pywrap_tensorflow_internal \u001b[39m=\u001b[39m swig_import_helper()\n\u001b[1;32m     29\u001b[0m \u001b[39mdel\u001b[39;00m swig_import_helper\n\nFile \u001b[0;32m/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py:24\u001b[0m, in \u001b[0;36mswig_import_helper\u001b[0;34m()\u001b[0m\n\u001b[1;32m     23\u001b[0m \u001b[39mtry\u001b[39;00m:\n\u001b[0;32m---> 24\u001b[0m     _mod \u001b[39m=\u001b[39m imp\u001b[39m.\u001b[39;49mload_module(\u001b[39m'\u001b[39;49m\u001b[39m_pywrap_tensorflow_internal\u001b[39;49m\u001b[39m'\u001b[39;49m, fp, pathname, description)\n\u001b[1;32m     25\u001b[0m \u001b[39mfinally\u001b[39;00m:\n\nFile \u001b[0;32m/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/imp.py:243\u001b[0m, in \u001b[0;36mload_module\u001b[0;34m(name, file, filename, details)\u001b[0m\n\u001b[1;32m    242\u001b[0m     \u001b[39melse\u001b[39;00m:\n\u001b[0;32m--> 243\u001b[0m         \u001b[39mreturn\u001b[39;00m load_dynamic(name, filename, file)\n\u001b[1;32m    244\u001b[0m \u001b[39melif\u001b[39;00m type_ \u001b[39m==\u001b[39m PKG_DIRECTORY:\n\nFile \u001b[0;32m/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/imp.py:343\u001b[0m, in \u001b[0;36mload_dynamic\u001b[0;34m(name, path, file)\u001b[0m\n\u001b[1;32m    341\u001b[0m spec \u001b[39m=\u001b[39m importlib\u001b[39m.\u001b[39mmachinery\u001b[39m.\u001b[39mModuleSpec(\n\u001b[1;32m    342\u001b[0m     name\u001b[39m=\u001b[39mname, loader\u001b[39m=\u001b[39mloader, origin\u001b[39m=\u001b[39mpath)\n\u001b[0;32m--> 343\u001b[0m \u001b[39mreturn\u001b[39;00m _load(spec)\n\n\u001b[0;31mImportError\u001b[0m: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so, 0x0006): tried: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so' (no such file), '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64'))\n\nDuring handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:\n\n\u001b[0;31mImportError\u001b[0m                               Traceback (most recent call last)\nCell \u001b[0;32mIn [14], line 1\u001b[0m\n\u001b[0;32m----> 1\u001b[0m \u001b[38;5;28;01mimport\u001b[39;00m \u001b[38;5;21;01mtensorflow\u001b[39;00m \u001b[38;5;28;01mas\u001b[39;00m \u001b[38;5;21;01mtf\u001b[39;00m\n\nFile \u001b[0;32m/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py:24\u001b[0m\n\u001b[1;32m     21\u001b[0m \u001b[39mimport\u001b[39;00m \u001b[39mos\u001b[39;00m \u001b[39mas\u001b[39;00m \u001b[39m_os\u001b[39;00m\n\u001b[1;32m     23\u001b[0m \u001b[39m# pylint: disable=g-bad-import-order\u001b[39;00m\n\u001b[0;32m---> 24\u001b[0m \u001b[39mfrom\u001b[39;00m \u001b[39mtensorflow\u001b[39;00m\u001b[39m.\u001b[39;00m\u001b[39mpython\u001b[39;00m \u001b[39mimport\u001b[39;00m pywrap_tensorflow  \u001b[39m# pylint: disable=unused-import\u001b[39;00m\n\u001b[1;32m     26\u001b[0m \u001b[39mtry\u001b[39;00m:\n\u001b[1;32m     27\u001b[0m   \u001b[39m# Add `estimator` attribute to allow access to estimator APIs via\u001b[39;00m\n\u001b[1;32m     28\u001b[0m   \u001b[39m# \"tf.estimator...\"\u001b[39;00m\n\u001b[1;32m     29\u001b[0m   \u001b[39mfrom\u001b[39;00m \u001b[39mtensorflow\u001b[39;00m\u001b[39m.\u001b[39;00m\u001b[39mpython\u001b[39;00m\u001b[39m.\u001b[39;00m\u001b[39mestimator\u001b[39;00m\u001b[39m.\u001b[39;00m\u001b[39mapi\u001b[39;00m \u001b[39mimport\u001b[39;00m estimator  \u001b[39m# pylint: disable=g-import-not-at-top\u001b[39;00m\n\nFile \u001b[0;32m/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py:49\u001b[0m\n\u001b[1;32m     32\u001b[0m \u001b[39m# TODO(drpng): write up instructions for editing this file in a doc and point to\u001b[39;00m\n\u001b[1;32m     33\u001b[0m \u001b[39m# the doc instead.\u001b[39;00m\n\u001b[1;32m     34\u001b[0m \u001b[39m# If you want to edit this file to expose modules in public tensorflow API, you\u001b[39;00m\n\u001b[0;32m   (...)\u001b[0m\n\u001b[1;32m     44\u001b[0m \u001b[39m# go/tf-wildcard-import\u001b[39;00m\n\u001b[1;32m     45\u001b[0m \u001b[39m# pylint: disable=wildcard-import,g-bad-import-order,g-import-not-at-top\u001b[39;00m\n\u001b[1;32m     47\u001b[0m \u001b[39mimport\u001b[39;00m \u001b[39mnumpy\u001b[39;00m \u001b[39mas\u001b[39;00m \u001b[39mnp\u001b[39;00m\n\u001b[0;32m---> 49\u001b[0m \u001b[39mfrom\u001b[39;00m \u001b[39mtensorflow\u001b[39;00m\u001b[39m.\u001b[39;00m\u001b[39mpython\u001b[39;00m \u001b[39mimport\u001b[39;00m pywrap_tensorflow\n\u001b[1;32m     51\u001b[0m \u001b[39mfrom\u001b[39;00m \u001b[39mtensorflow\u001b[39;00m\u001b[39m.\u001b[39;00m\u001b[39mpython\u001b[39;00m\u001b[39m.\u001b[39;00m\u001b[39mtools\u001b[39;00m \u001b[39mimport\u001b[39;00m component_api_helper\n\u001b[1;32m     52\u001b[0m component_api_helper\u001b[39m.\u001b[39mpackage_hook(\n\u001b[1;32m     53\u001b[0m     parent_package_str\u001b[39m=\u001b[39m\u001b[39m'\u001b[39m\u001b[39mtensorflow.python\u001b[39m\u001b[39m'\u001b[39m,\n\u001b[1;32m     54\u001b[0m     child_package_str\u001b[39m=\u001b[39m(\n\u001b[1;32m     55\u001b[0m         \u001b[39m'\u001b[39m\u001b[39mtensorflow_estimator.python.estimator\u001b[39m\u001b[39m'\u001b[39m))\n\nFile \u001b[0;32m/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py:74\u001b[0m\n\u001b[1;32m     69\u001b[0m \u001b[39mexcept\u001b[39;00m \u001b[39mImportError\u001b[39;00m:\n\u001b[1;32m     70\u001b[0m   msg \u001b[39m=\u001b[39m \u001b[39m\"\"\"\u001b[39m\u001b[39m%s\u001b[39;00m\u001b[39m\\n\u001b[39;00m\u001b[39m\\n\u001b[39;00m\u001b[39mFailed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.\u001b[39m\u001b[39m\\n\u001b[39;00m\n\u001b[1;32m     71\u001b[0m \u001b[39mSee https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors\u001b[39m\u001b[39m\\n\u001b[39;00m\n\u001b[1;32m     72\u001b[0m \u001b[39mfor some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace\u001b[39m\n\u001b[1;32m     73\u001b[0m \u001b[39mabove this error message when asking for help.\u001b[39m\u001b[39m\"\"\"\u001b[39m \u001b[39m%\u001b[39m traceback\u001b[39m.\u001b[39mformat_exc()\n\u001b[0;32m---> 74\u001b[0m   \u001b[39mraise\u001b[39;00m \u001b[39mImportError\u001b[39;00m(msg)\n\n\u001b[0;31mImportError\u001b[0m: Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py\", line 58, in <module>\n    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *\n  File \"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py\", line 28, in <module>\n    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()\n  File \"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py\", line 24, in swig_import_helper\n    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)\n  File \"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/imp.py\", line 243, in load_module\n    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)\n  File \"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/imp.py\", line 343, in load_dynamic\n    return _load(spec)\nImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so, 0x0006): tried: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so' (no such file), '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64'))\n\n\nFailed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.\n\nSee https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors\n\nfor some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace\nabove this error message when asking for help."
```

I tried importing the tensorflow and keras libraries but I'm getting this error out of nowhere.
It used to work before but suddenly this error.

Comment: tf.estimator( ) included CPU architecture because it is a shared library such as Tensorboard and TensorFlow-hub.

Comment: I didnt understand can you explain what i have to do

Comment: Removed and re-install the correct compatibilities versions, list the install libraries Tensorflow, Keras, Tensorflow estimators, ... are the same versions.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the `Tensorflow` is not installed properly in your system. Please follow the steps below to install `Tensorflow` in your system.

```
# Requires the latest pip
pip install --upgrade pip

# Current stable release for CPU and GPU
pip install tensorflow

# Check the installed tensorflow version
import tensorflow as tf
tf.__version__
```

Or you can follow `step by step instructions` mentioned in this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip) to install `TensorFlow` using Conda environment by checking the Hardware and Software requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `python-dev`:

```
sudo apt install python-dev
```

After that also you can install `grpcio`.